# Sidebar Issue - Change From HTML Listing

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

Hi I wonder whether someone could help me please, as I've got myself into a bit of a pickle with this and I'm not sure how to resolve this.

I'm using [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/mylocationstest.html) page to give the user the functionality of being able to select and deselect markers on the map via check boxes. They can then click on any marker, either on the map, or via the left hand sidebar, select a radius setting from the drop down menu in the right hand sidebar and search for POI's within that given radius.

What I'm trying to do is change the sidebar on the left hand side to match the format of the one on the right.

I know that the piece of code that needs to change is this:

```
function myclick(i) { 
            google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i],"click"); 
            } 

            // == rebuilds the sidebar to match the markers currently displayed == 
            function makeSidebar() { 
            var html = ""; 
            for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) { 
            if (gmarkers[i].getVisible()) { 
            html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + gmarkers[i].myname + " - " + gmarkers[i].myfinds + " Finds made" + '<\/a><br>'; 
            } 
            } 
            document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = html; 
            }
```

I've tried replacing it with the code below which is taken from the piece of script which creates the sidebar on the right hand side.

```
function createSidebarEntry(marker2, sitedescription, distance) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
        var html2 = '<b>' + sitedescription + '</b> (' + distance.toFixed(1) + '  miles) <br/>';
    div.innerHTML = html2;
    div.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    div.style.marginBottom = '5px'; 
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, 'click', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker2, 'click');
    });
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, 'mouseover', function() {
    div.style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
    });
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, 'mouseout', function() {
    div.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    });
    return div;
    }
```

[This](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/mylocationstest1.html) is what I've done so far. I can get the markers to appear on the map but I can't get the sidebar on the left hand side to render.

I've been working on this for a number of days now and I just seem to be going round in circles. I just wondered whether someone could take a look at this please and let me know where I've gone wrong.

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: What browser are you using - the sidebar renders for me in Chrome (and do you mean left or right for the sidebar)

Comment: Hi, many thanks for replying to my post. The first link in my post, shows the page as it is at the moment.If you click on 'Test Location 2' in the sidebar on the left, select '25' from the drop down menu on the right side of the page & click 'Select Locations', a sidebar will be created on the right. As you'll see the format is different to the one on the left.It's this that I'd like to change i.e. I'd like the sidebar on the left to look exactly like the one on the right. The second link in my post shows what I've being working on to try & achieve this, but without any luck. Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

Why you are surprised it doesn't work? The problem is in your function `makeSidebar()`, which should probably do the job (?) but as it is written it does something strange... First you create a a new `div` which you don't place anywhere in the dom (it should probably be placed in the sidebar, but the sidebar is not used in this function!). The function performs a for-loop but it returns in first iteration! So in fact it does nothing.

Go ahead and debug your code. Use Firebug debugger to track it down!

Comment: Hi, I admit I am fairly new to this, you can probably tell. I have used Firebug before to identify any errors, but when I looked at this page it showed no errors, so, perhaps because of my lack of knowledge, I wasn't sure where the error(s) arose. kind regards

Comment: It just requires some work, but it's nothing really complicated. Maybe first do yourself a thorough code review, it will save you time with the debugging. Good luck!